# Accessing methods from function constructors

Tags: javascript, instance

How can the retirementAge method access the value of calculateAge method in the same Person function constructor?
[image]

Comment: please add the code as text, not as image. please have a look here, too: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could simply call it within the `retirementAge` method inside the constructor function

```
this.retirementAge = function() {
   console.log(66 - this.calculateAge())
}
```

and use it like

```
john.retirementAge();
```

Comment: `calculateAge()` doesn’t  return a value.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your calculateAge method return a value, you will be able to access it in the retirementAge method.
Try this:

```
this.calculateAge = function () {
    return 2018 - this.yearOfBirth
  }
  this.retirementAge = function () {
    return 66 - this.calculateAge()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the methods to retun a value and then use `this.calculateAge()` in the method for getting the value.

```js
var Person = function(name, yearOfBirth, job) {
        this.name = name;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        this.job = job;
        this.calculateAge = function() {
            return 2018 - this.yearOfBirth;
        };
        this.retirementAge = function() {
            return 66 - this.calculateAge();
        }
    };

var john = new Person("John", 1998, 'teacher');

console.log(john.retirementAge());
console.log(john.calculateAge());
```